# CSS GRID - Span Image over multiple rows - without effecting the height of all rows - cant figure it out

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to span a **image** over **4 rows** without effecting the height of every row in the **2 column**. But every time I resize the image the other rows get huge gaps also there is gap on the right of the image. I am really confused ([Image of grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPeOO.png)). I would really appreciate a explanation, why my grid areas are not working.

### CSS and HTML:

```css
.center-row {
  width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.worksteps {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "img workstep1"
    "img workstep2"
    "img workstep3"
    "img downloadActions";
}

.app-display-frame {
  grid-area: img;
}

.app-display {
  width: 40%;
}

.workstep--1 {
  grid-area: workstep1;
}

.workstep--2 {
  grid-area: workstep2;
}

.workstep--3 {
  grid-area: workstep3;
}

.download-actions {
  grid-area: downloadActions;
}

.download-actions img {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<section class="steps">
  <div class="center-row">
    <h2>How it works; simple as 1, 2, 3</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="center-row">
    <div class="worksteps">
      <div class="app-display-frame">
        <img
          class="app-display"
          src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxdboxbyb/image/upload/v1616248492/SHOKU/x46urbotnvmt0qkqxyk8.png"
          alt="Shoku app on Iphone"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="workstep--1 workstep">
        <div>1</div>
        <p>
          Choose the subscription plan that best fits your needs and sign
          up today.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="workstep--2 workstep">
        <div>2</div>
        <p>
          Order your delicious meal using our mobile app or website. Or
          you can even call us!
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="workstep--3 workstep">
        <div>3</div>
        <p>
          Enjoy your meal after less than 20 minutes. See you the next
          time!
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="download-actions">
        <a class="button-app" href="">
          <img
            src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxdboxbyb/image/upload/v1616240033/SHOKU/a9l7agaqtiu9ivzsk89o.svg"
            alt="App Store Button"
        /></a>
        <a class="button-app" href="">
          <img
            src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxdboxbyb/image/upload/v1616240021/SHOKU/rfjt7c8vpjv6ttptculu.png"
            alt="Play Store Button"
          />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: That's standard for CSS-Grid so if you do not want that behaviour I suggest you use a different layout method or adjust your methodology. You have specifically in your CSS that the height of the combined right rows should match the left column.

Comment: Do you need this result? - https://ibb.co/Fw4VCgF Here the lines on the right are not stretched in height.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov The lines not even stretch if you resize the image on the left? would be nice

Comment: @MrB, How would you comment on my solutions?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov thanks for both solutions. I went for the first one. It pretty much helped me, to archive my goal. But Im quite amazed that the forth value of the row, had such a great influence on the result.

Comment: @MrB, Yes, because the fourth row is 1fr and therefore takes up all the free space, compressing all other rows with auto space. I was glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will offer two solutions.

In the first solution, the side text list does not depend on the image height except for the last row. To do this, you need to set **1fr** for the last row, with the help of then all the rows that are higher to receive the height of their content.

```
.worksteps {
  ...
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto 1fr;
  ...
}
```

```css
.center-row {
  width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.worksteps {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "img workstep1"
    "img workstep2"
    "img workstep3"
    "img downloadActions";
}

.app-display-frame {
  grid-area: img;
}

.app-display {
  width: 40%;
}

.workstep--1 {
  grid-area: workstep1;
}

.workstep--2 {
  grid-area: workstep2;
}

.workstep--3 {
  grid-area: workstep3;
}

.download-actions {
  grid-area: downloadActions;
}

.download-actions img {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<section class="steps">
  <div class="center-row">
    <h2>How it works; simple as 1, 2, 3</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="center-row">
    <div class="worksteps">
      <div class="app-display-frame">
        <img
          class="app-display"
          src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1f/32/de/1f32de75ae0a1ac218a902f6f361a6d7.jpg"
          alt="Shoku app on Iphone"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="workstep--1 workstep">
        <div>1</div>
        <p>
          Choose the subscription plan that best fits your needs and sign
          up today.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="workstep--2 workstep">
        <div>2</div>
        <p>
          Order your delicious meal using our mobile app or website. Or
          you can even call us!
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="workstep--3 workstep">
        <div>3</div>
        <p>
          Enjoy your meal after less than 20 minutes. See you the next
          time!
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="download-actions">
        <a class="button-app" href="">
          <img
            src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxdboxbyb/image/upload/v1616240033/SHOKU/a9l7agaqtiu9ivzsk89o.svg"
            alt="App Store Button"
        /></a>
        <a class="button-app" href="">
          <img
            src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxdboxbyb/image/upload/v1616240021/SHOKU/rfjt7c8vpjv6ttptculu.png"
            alt="Play Store Button"
          />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The second solution builds on the first solution, but with the addition of additional `img` rules and `.worksteps` selector.

For the img tag add a `height: 100%` and `object-fit: contain`. Like that:

```
.app-display {
    ...
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

And the most important thing in this solution is the addition of `max-height: 1px` to `.worksteps`. This will prevent the image from leaving the grid, and the height of all rows will be made according to the height of its content. This is a **lifehack** solution. Like that:

```
.worksteps {
  ...
  max-height: 1px;
}
```

```css
.center-row {
  width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.worksteps {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "img workstep1"
    "img workstep2"
    "img workstep3"
    "img downloadActions";
  max-height: 1px;
}

.app-display-frame {
  grid-area: img;
}

.app-display {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.workstep--1 {
  grid-area: workstep1;
}

.workstep--2 {
  grid-area: workstep2;
}

.workstep--3 {
  grid-area: workstep3;
}

.download-actions {
  grid-area: downloadActions;
}

.download-actions img {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<section class="steps">
  <div class="center-row">
    <h2>How it works; simple as 1, 2, 3</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="center-row">
    <div class="worksteps">
      <div class="app-display-frame">
        <img
          class="app-display"
          src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1f/32/de/1f32de75ae0a1ac218a902f6f361a6d7.jpg"
          alt="Shoku app on Iphone"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="workstep--1 workstep">
        <div>1</div>
        <p>
          Choose the subscription plan that best fits your needs and sign
          up today.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="workstep--2 workstep">
        <div>2</div>
        <p>
          Order your delicious meal using our mobile app or website. Or
          you can even call us!
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="workstep--3 workstep">
        <div>3</div>
        <p>
          Enjoy your meal after less than 20 minutes. See you the next
          time!
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="download-actions">
        <a class="button-app" href="">
          <img
            src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxdboxbyb/image/upload/v1616240033/SHOKU/a9l7agaqtiu9ivzsk89o.svg"
            alt="App Store Button"
        /></a>
        <a class="button-app" href="">
          <img
            src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxdboxbyb/image/upload/v1616240021/SHOKU/rfjt7c8vpjv6ttptculu.png"
            alt="Play Store Button"
          />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```